# Cannot run the newman command on windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, postman, postman-newman

I tried to install newman globally but no luck and here is what I did:
First I installed newman as follows:
[image: image.png]
Then I ran the command `newman -h` in another command prompt window:
[image: image.png]

> 'newman' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I looked for the newman module in the following folders but I didn't find any:

- `C:\Users\my-username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`
- `C:\Users\my-username\AppData\Roaming\npm`
- `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules`

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cause:

After spending some time trying to solve this, I found out that npm is not configured correctly, and it installs the module in another directory.

### Solution:

Make sure that npm prefix is set to the path where NodeJs is installed using the following command:

`npm config get prefix`

[image]

In my case, I already installed NodeJS before running `npm install -g newman` in the following path:

[image]

So what I did to solve the issue, is to run the following command:

`npm config set prefix "C:\Program Files\nodejs"`

[image]

and then I re-installed Newman globally with `npm install -g npm` and that's all.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71785032/7733418 , the last command for installing Newman should be
`npm install -g newman`, instead of
`npm install -g npm`.

Comment: Are you commenting on a mistake in the existing answer? Or are you saying thanks for the existing answer?  Or is this meant to be an answer according to [answer]?

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32759980)

Comment: The solution works but the last command is a mistake. So I corrected the mistake, and I did it politely.

Comment: Please [edit] and propose this as a solution in a standalone answer. Feel free to explain which disadvantage the other solution has. Consider that it might be correct in a different context or environment. For now I clarified your reference (hope I got it right).